# Has WO publication number: 2003023175 lapsed

Tags: lapsed, wpo

On the German Patent offece web site it states this patent has lapsed

[German Patent Office link](https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/register?lang=en)

But are they refering only to the local DE and EP versions or is the WO verison lapsed too ?
How do I find out ?

Espacenet only seems to concern the EP version which shows it as lapsed.

Logikman

Comment: The WO version is the number of the PCT filing. It does not lapse since it is never, itself, granted. It is no longer  operative after the time to enter the national stage in all 140+ PCT countries is past at the 31 month time for most.

Comment: The EP register has a long list of places it has lapsed but I do not know if is everywhere that it was validated or if  EPO umbrella patent has lapsed. Besides going into the EPO it also entered the national stage  (from the PCT) in Japan and and Poland. https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2003023175&tab=NATIONALPHASE The JP application is shown as withdrawn. Not sure about status in Poland https://grab.uprp.pl/PropertiesProtection/Site%20pages/Quick%20search.aspx?wersja=english.

Comment: thanks George I had not picked up that the WO version was like a summary of all the national patents. I have onbly experienced Uk and EP patents so di not reayl know how the WO/PCT operated. Logikman

Comment: logikman, if you type an @ symbol before George White it'll send him a message so he knows you've directed a comment to him.

Comment: @logikman - WO/PCT is not really a summary of national patents. It is the number of a PCT filing that represents an initial filing in the numerous PCT countries. It could lead to national stages in specific places. One can file  in many  countries directly without a PCT filing at all or could file a PCT that branches into several countries + other direct filings. Looking at PCT data would not show the direct filings.

Comment: @Eric Shain  thanks for the Tip Eric had not picked that up when I registered.

Comment: @George White - The federated register on Espacent shows the EP lapsed 09.09.2015. Is the PCT reliant on the EP or the original DE patent. Like you cannot find anything about the PL version on any of the usual data bases and the Polish Patent office site seems to revert to polish after the inital search page so cannot work out if that one is still active?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reliant". A German application and an EP application were used as priority documents when the PCT was filed. link to polish patent office record https://grab.uprp.pl/PropertiesProtection/Site%20pages/Quick%20search.aspx?wersja=english